# Is there something like google translate but for desktop?

Tags: debian, dictionary

I saw we have freeict-all in debian.

```
    $ sudo aptitude install dict-freedict-all
    [sudo] password for shirish: 
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
   dict-freedict-afr-deu{a} dict-freedict-afr-eng{a} dict-freedict-all


dict-freedict-ara-eng{a} dict-freedict-bre-fra{a} dict-freedict-ces-eng{a}
dict-freedict-ckb-kmr{a} dict-freedict-cym-eng{a} dict-freedict-dan-eng{a}dict-freedict-deu-eng{a} dict-freedict-deu-fra{a} dict-freedict-deu-ita{a} dict-freedict-deu-kur{a} dict-freedict-deu-nld{a} dict-freedict-deu-por{a} dict-freedict-deu-swe{a} dict-freedict-deu-tur{a} dict-freedict-eng-afr{a} dict-freedict-eng-ara{a} dict-freedict-eng-ces{a} dict-freedict-eng-cym{a} dict-freedict-eng-deu{a} dict-freedict-eng-ell{a} dict-freedict-eng-fra{a} dict-freedict-eng-gle{a} dict-freedict-eng-hin{a} dict-freedict-eng-hrv{a} dict-freedict-eng-hun{a} dict-freedict-eng-ita{a} dict-freedict-eng-lat{a} dict-freedict-eng-lit{a} dict-freedict-eng-nld{a} dict-freedict-eng-pol{a} dict-freedict-eng-por{a} dict-freedict-eng-rom{a} dict-freedict-eng-rus{a} dict-freedict-eng-spa{a} dict-freedict-eng-srp{a} dict-freedict-eng-swe{a} dict-freedict-eng-swh{a} dict-freedict-eng-tur{a} dict-freedict-fra-bre{a} dict-freedict-fra-deu{a} dict-freedict-fra-eng{a} dict-freedict-fra-nld{a} dict-freedict-gla-deu{a} dict-freedict-gle-eng{a} dict-freedict-gle-pol{a} dict-freedict-hrv-eng{a} dict-freedict-hun-eng{a} dict-freedict-isl-eng{a} dict-freedict-ita-deu{a} dict-freedict-ita-eng{a} dict-freedict-jpn-deu{a} dict-freedict-jpn-eng{a} dict-freedict-jpn-fra{a} dict-freedict-jpn-rus{a} dict-freedict-kha-deu{a} dict-freedict-kha-eng{a} dict-freedict-kur-deu{a} dict-freedict-kur-eng{a} dict-freedict-kur-tur{a} dict-freedict-lat-deu{a} dict-freedict-lat-eng{a} dict-freedict-lit-eng{a} dict-freedict-mkd-bul{a} dict-freedict-nld-deu{a} dict-freedict-nld-eng{a} dict-freedict-nld-fra{a} dict-freedict-nno-nob{a} dict-freedict-oci-cat{a} dict-freedict-pol-gle{a} dict-freedict-por-deu{a} dict-freedict-por-eng{a} dict-freedict-san-deu{a} dict-freedict-slk-eng{a} dict-freedict-spa-ast{a} dict-freedict-spa-eng{a} dict-freedict-spa-por{a} dict-freedict-srp-eng{a} dict-freedict-swe-deu{a} dict-freedict-swe-eng{a} dict-freedict-swh-eng{a} dict-freedict-swh-pol{a} dict-freedict-tur-deu{a} dict-freedict-tur-eng{a} 
        0 packages upgraded, 86 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
        Need to get 48.9 MB of archives. After unpacking 80.1 MB will be used.
        Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] n
```

My use-case is simple, I just want to able to translate phrases from a different language without needing to go to the web. Is it possible or not using the above tool. Even if it's a bit broken, grammar syntax etc. might be worthwhile.

Comment: @grump that's not true, freedict is a dictionary, not a word list. However, they're not a translation service, and can only help you translate things if you understand the grammar, which is less than what an automated translation service like google translate can do.

Comment: @WouterVerhelst mea culpa

Answer (score 10):

A command line tool : [`translate-shell`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/translate-shell)

> Translate Shell (formerly Google Translate CLI) is a command-line translator powered by Google Translate (default), Bing Translator, Yandex.Translate, DeepL Translator and Apertium. It gives you easy access to one of these translation engines in your terminal.

```
apt install translate-shell
```

e,g:

```
trans 'Salut!, Bonjour!, Soyez le bienvenu!'
```

Sample output:

```
Salut!, Bonjour!, Soyez le bienvenu!
(null)

Hi!, Hello!, Welcome!
/null/

Translations of Salut!, Bonjour!, Soyez le bienvenu!
[ Français -> English ]

Salut!, Bonjour!, Soyez le bienvenu!
    Hi!, Hello!, Welcome!
```

See `trans --help` for more details.

You can use the `-p` option to activate the speech synthesizer:

```
trans 'Buenos días. ¿Cómo estás?' -p
```

To change the target Language use`[source_LANG]:[target_LANG]` e,g: (from Spanish to French):

```
trans es:fr 'Buenos días. ¿Cómo estás?'
```

or:

```
trans -s es -t fr 'Buenos días. ¿Cómo estás?'
```

[The home page on github.](https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell)

Answer (score 4):

[`weboob`](http://weboob.org/) can also do this:

> Weboob is a collection of applications able to interact with websites,
>   without requiring the user to open them in a browser. It also provides
>   well-defined APIs to talk to websites lacking one.

I found that `Ubuntu 16.04.3 lts` has an old version of `weboob` is
it's best to clone it directly from `git`:

```
$ git clone https://git.weboob.org/weboob/devel.git weboob && cd weboob
```

Start `translaboob` module manually:

```
$ ./tools/local_run.sh  translaboob
```

At the first run you'll have to choose a backend you want to use:

```
Warning: there is currently no configured backend for translaboob
Do you want to configure backends? (Y/n): Y

Available modules:
1) [ ] ebonics           English to Ebonics translation service
2) [ ] googletranslate   Google translation web service
3) [ ] larousse          larousse dictionary translations
4) [ ] wordreference     Free online translator
a) --all--               install all backends
q) --stop--
```

In this example we choose `googletranslate`:

```
Select a backend to create (q to stop): 2
Backend "googletranslate" successfully added.

Available modules:
1) [ ] ebonics           English to Ebonics translation service
2) [X] googletranslate   Google translation web service
3) [ ] larousse          larousse dictionary translations
4) [ ] wordreference     Free online translator
a) --all--               install all backends
q) --stop--
```

After pressing `q` you can type a sentence to translate, for example:

```
Select a backend to create (q to stop): q
Right right!
Welcome to translaboob v1.4

Copyright(C) 2012-2018 Lucien Loiseau
This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU Affero General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

Type "help" to display available commands.

Loaded backends: googletranslate

translaboob> translate en de 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
* googletranslate
        Der schnelle braune Fuchs springt über den faulen Hund
translaboob> translate en ko 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'
* googletranslate
        빠른 갈색 여우는 게으른 개를 뛰어 넘습니다.
```

Comment: The [`weboob`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/weboob) package is available through apt.

Comment: Yes, I know but for example in `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` it's version `1.1` which is very old and `translaboob` does not work. I also said that in my answer.

Comment: one of the dependencies of weboob is no longer available, see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866493